# CSS: Exclude text from background overlay

Tags: html, css

I have a big image with a dark overlay covering the front of my webpage. I want to add a div filled with bright text on top of the overlay.

Is there a way to position the div so as to exclude it from the overlay?

HTML:

```css
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  top: 70px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: -200px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.about-us {
  background-image: url("img.jpg");
  width: 1100px;
  height: 731px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="about-us">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="intro">
      <h2>Catchy title</h2>
      <p>Small Para</p>
      <h1>More txt</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how about:  `z-index: 2;` ?

Comment: That doesn't seem to have an effect

Comment: What really is the problem? -- https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/7d11esdt/

Comment: You'll need to set a `background-color` too.

Comment: You description and request is unclear...perhaps you could provide us with an image of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Abhitalks, thank you! That did work. I had other styling going on that was affecting the text and overwriting my styling.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
h2 {
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Assuming that was what you wanted on top.

Comment: All of the text in 'intro' is white. The overlay, though, is forming a shadow over the text AND the image, and I only want it to shadow the image. z-index is having no effect.

Comment: Nothing you included indicated that.  My mind reading skills are poor.

Comment: I thought I was clear enough in my question- guess not clear enough! Sorry about that. I was trying to do exactly what @Abhitalks posted here: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/7d11esdt/

Answer (score 0):

Use a pseudo element instead of an overlay element.

```
.about-us:before {
      content:"";
      position: absolute;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
      top: 70px;
      left: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      bottom: -200px;
}
```

Also you need to explicitly specify `position` property for intro element in able to interact with the content:

```
.intro {
  position: relative;
}
```

See example [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbrvVr)